# How to find array value of a data model in a view container of specific row of that array that user typed?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know how to find array value of that particular index which user has typed. I had connected that array to my data model which contain 2 values ?

I have tried .contain value after implementing a new variable of the data model but it hasn't worked

```
let productsNamess = document.data()["ProductName"] as! String
let quantityGame = document.data()["Quantity"] as! String

// making a new net stock data incoming class
let newClassForProducts = dataModelOutgoing()
newClassForProducts.productName = productsNamess
newClassForProducts.quantity = Int(quantityGame)

// forward data to main dataincoming main class
self.dataIncoming.append(newClassForProducts)
```

I dont know how to take data out of an array which contains two values in one array.

Comment: how did you try?

Comment: Could you provide more relevant example? Not getting your question.